# Developer has asked me to "send SSH keys to them"

Tags: ssh

I have created SSH keys to access a server on Digital Ocean and I can access it by using:

```
ssh root@123.123.123.123
```

If I cd I can see the server and all is good.

A developer who needs to work on this project is asking me to provide them with the SSH keys.

I am assuming I do this by sending them the "public key" right?

I did that by:

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

So I sent developer the key which I am assuming is public, hence the .pub

However, the bit that I just can't work out is how can that work for him to access the server? I mean, surely I have to agree or allow the keys to match?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct - the .pub is the public key, and you are right about "to agree or allow keys to match".

The developer creates their own public/private key.  They give you the public part.  You put the public part in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the machine in question.  Then, said developer can access the machine.